# How to wait for database transaction to complete it operation and return value in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, database, cordova-2.0.0

I am creating an app which fetch the data from the database on startup for that i want to create an js which will perform the database transaction and return the array element through which i will create the text-box and button etc.Know the problem is when I call the function on the onload like **elementArray=fetchdata();**   and then db.transaction in js will fetch the data from the database and return and array but when i call the function in js it call the function and start execution but does not wait for the db.transaction to complete and starts futher execution.I want to wait untill db.transaction complete its operation and then execute further operation.
here is the dynamic_form.js file i create to fetch the data from the database:

```
var elementArray=new Array();
function fetchdata(){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("Select * from contactTable",[],function(tx,results){
        for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
            var element=new Object();
            element.Name=results.rows.item(i).name;
            element.Lastname=results.rows.item(i).last_name;
            element.Mobile=resulst.rows.item(i).mobile_no;
            // ****and so on***//
            elementArray[i]=element;
        }
        return elementArray;
    });
});}
```

here is the code in the html file it loads the js file  :

```
function dbTranscation()
    {
        console.log("$ function");
        var elementArray=fetchdata();
                       // after this it sould call this function
          createfield();

    }
```

Comment: Can you check the returned element Array, if it contains data, then only call the method createfield() OR add the createfield as a callback funtion with the returned elementArray.

Comment: Thats where I'm stuck how the check the return elementArray can you give a some example of it plz it would be great help.@Sheetal

Comment: I tried this but before it returns a value from js files it executes the if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With callback:

var elementArray=new Array();
function fetchdata(callback){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("Select * from contactTable",[],function(tx,results){
        for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
            var element=new Object();
            element.Name=results.rows.item(i).name;
            element.Lastname=results.rows.item(i).last_name;
            element.Mobile=resulst.rows.item(i).mobile_no;
            // ****and so on***//
            elementArray[i]=element;
        }
        callback(elementArray);
    });
});}

function dbTranscation()
{
        console.log("$ function");
        fetchdata(createfield);

}

// another function 
function createfield(elementArray)
{ 
   // some logic 
};
```

Comment: can i put the With callback in the js file so i can just call it whenever i want to use it in different pages..@sheetal

Comment: hey thanks for your answer I have solved the problem i'm calling the function from the js files to create the fields but know the problem is it does not create any thing in the page. I checked whether it elementArray contains the data or not its containing data.

Comment: great, but your original issue is resolved right? so please mark the answer resolved.

Comment: can you check this question also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18271338/2307391 @sheetal

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementArray=new Array();
function fetchdata(callbackFN){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("Select * from contactTable",[],function(tx,results){
        for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
            var element=new Object();
            element.Name=results.rows.item(i).name;
            element.Lastname=results.rows.item(i).last_name;
            element.Mobile=resulst.rows.item(i).mobile_no;
            // ****and so on***//
            elementArray[i]=element;
        }
        callbackFN();
    });
});}

// you can call function with call back

function dbTranscation() {
        console.log("$ function");        
        fetchdata(function (){
            createfield();    
        });
}

// you can define "fetchdata" function in globally and can access from any other pages
```

Comment: can you check this question also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18271338/2307391 @JDev